# The continuity of a function that can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> The function $F(x) : = \int \limits _x^{x^2} \dfrac{\sin t}{t} dt$ is differentiable on $(1, \infty)$.

How can one go about showing that this is true? Since you can't express this integral in terms of elementary functions, I wouldn't really know how to prove differentiability.

Also, the fact that this integral exists must imply differentiability, right?

Comment: compute $$\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What do you mean compute it?

Comment: what i have written down this term

Comment: All right, since you know how to compute it, what does it equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integrand is continuous on $[1,\infty)$, the integral $g(x)=\int_1^x \frac{\sin t}t\,dt$ exists and is differentiable on $[1,\infty)$.

Your $F(x)$ is then $g(x^2)-g(x)$ which is differentiable by the chain rule and subtraction rule.

Comment: I don't really understand the first sentence. How does it being bounded on $[0, \infty]$ mean it exists?

Comment: @USSLimitz: I was not completely sharp there. It is of course enough that the integrand is _continuous_; the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus takes care of the rest.

Comment: So you say that $g(x)=\int_1^x \frac{\sin t}t\,dt$ exists for every $x \in [1, \infty) $, so that means that$ \int_x^{x^2} \frac{\sin t}t\,dt$ must also exist for every $ x \in [1, \infty)$

Comment: @USSLimitz: Yes, but we already know that because $[x,x^2]$ is a subinterval of $[1,\infty)$ where we have already observed that the integrand is continuous.

Comment: Sounds logical, thanks. A final question though. Continuity on its own is not enough to imply differentiability. When then is it enough in this case?

Comment: @USSLimitz: Continuity _of the integrand_ is enough to imply that the indefinite _integral_ is differentiable -- that's what the Fundamental Theorem says! (Note that "integrand" and "integral" are different words -- the integrand is the function that is _being integrated_).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compute the integral in order to derive it next. It is true in general that if $f, g$ are derivable functions on $(a,b)$, so will be $\int \limits _{f(x)} ^{g(x)} \varphi (t) \Bbb d t$, and $\dfrac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d x} \int \limits _{f(x)} ^{g(x)} \varphi (t) \Bbb d t = \varphi (g(x)) g'(x) - \varphi (f(x)) f'(x)$.

In your case $F'(x) = \dfrac {\sin x^2} {x^2} 2x - \dfrac {\sin x} x = \dfrac {2 \sin x^2 - \sin x} x$.